# Display div below clickable link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following:

```
<a class="noteLink">Note Name</a>
<div class="note">Full Note Details</div>
<a class="noteLink">Note Name</a>
<div class="note">Full Note Details</div>
<a class="noteLink">Note Name</a>
<div class="note">Full Note Details</div>
```

Where all the "note" divs are **hidden by default**, I'd like to show the one that relates to the `button` that is clicked when it's clicked.

Is there an easier way than something like:

```
$('#UniqueNoteLink').click(function() {
    $('#UniqueNoteID').toggle();
});
```

For each note?

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's various traversal functions: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the element you want to toggle comes right after the clicked element, you could just use `next()`

```js
$('.noteLink').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="noteLink">Note Name</a>
<div class="note">Full Note Details</div>
<a class="noteLink">Note Name</a>
<div class="note">Full Note Details</div>
<a class="noteLink">Note Name</a>
<div class="note">Full Note Details</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using classes.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".note").hide();
  $(".noteLink").click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
a {cursor: pointer; display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="noteLink">Note Name</a>
<div class="note">Full Note Details</div>
<a class="noteLink">Note Name</a>
<div class="note">Full Note Details</div>
<a class="noteLink">Note Name</a>
<div class="note">Full Note Details</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.clickables{
    border:1px solid #999999;
}
.deepclickables{
    margin:5px;
    border:1px dotted #999999;
}
```

---

```
<div class="clickables">
    <span onClick="javascript:clickables()">Clickables</span>
    <div id="clicka" class="deepclickables">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function clickables(){
    document.getElementById('clicka').innerHTML = "Yo yo yo"
}
</script>
```

**or**

```
function clickable(){
    document.getElementById('clickable').innerHTML = "content";
}
Use onClick to call it

<div id="click" onClick="javascript:clickable();">Click me!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.next()` would be the ideal solution. But if you are able to wrap your `.note` and `.noteLink` into a `label` tag with a checkbox, you may not need javescript to do this trick. Here is an example:

```css
input, 
.note {
  display: none;
}

label,
input:checked ~ div {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type=checkbox>
  <a class="noteLink">Note Name</a>
  <div class="note">Full Note Details</div>
</label>

<label>
  <input type=checkbox>
  <a class="noteLink">Note Name</a>
  <div class="note">Full Note Details</div>
</label>

<label>
  <input type=checkbox>
  <a class="noteLink">Note Name</a>
  <div class="note">Full Note Details</div>
</label>
```